# Yosemite three-finger lookup not working

Tags: macos

I have enabled the three-finger lookup, but it is not working since I upgrade to Yosemite. How to fix it?

Comment: You can always hover over the word and press Command-Control-D.

Comment: @0942v8653 nice tip. I didn't know that one.

Answer (score 4):

Are you running [Scroll Reverser](https://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/)? It causes the bug. Just quit Scroll Reverser.

Comment: Why the down vote? I am indeed using it! I see. This is interesting.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with force touch if you have one of the new macbook pro - if it's on force touch under trackpad -> point and click -> Lookup and data detectors then change it to tap three fingers and it should work.

Comment: This was the thing for me. They somehow changed the default. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking into System Preferences > Trackpad? I can't tell if you are referring to Mission Control swipe up with three fingers, but that's definitely still under the menu in trackpad and can be enabled.

Comment: No, I am referrring to looking up a word in the dictionary.

Comment: That's still under the trackpad menu! It's the first tab, "Point and Click" but it seems to be disabled by default in Yosemite. You can just check it again and it should work (worked for me).

Comment: Thanks, I do have checked, and everything is ticked... But still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and used these two commands to disable and then re-enable bluetooth. Seemed to revive my issues.

However I have noticed that 3-finger lookup works in some applications and not in others. For instance no problem in my web browsers but not so great in my vm or a few Microsoft products.

Comment: This worked for me when using my MBP as a laptop without a Magic Trackpad 2 that was in range and connected via bluetooth.